# How to calculate accurately the last 7 day unanswered questions?

Tags: support, statistics

`[google-sheets] created:7d.. is:question` returns 23 questions
`[google-sheets] created:7d.. is:question isanswered:0` returns 18 questions

18/23 * 100 = 78.2 (truncated)

but https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/google-sheets/topusers shows 73.9% unanswered

What am I missing / doing wrong? Are the stats from the above link wrong?